# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined ( ReactJS & AJAX)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, reactjs

Try show in table my array. Array get from AJAX request in Action. I'm using Redux

```
class IncomeProfile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.IncomeListProfile();
      }

render() {
        var elems = this.props.items.course_list;
      console.log(elems);
        return (
          <div>
            <table>
              {elems.map((item) => (

              <tr key={item.course_id}>
                <td>{item.name}</td>
              </tr>

              ))}
            </table>
          </div>
        )
      }

}

const mapDispatchToProps = function(dispatch) {
  return {
      IncomeListProfile: () => dispatch(IncomeProfileList())
      }
  }

const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  var mystore = state.toArray();
  //console.log(mystore[6]);
  return {
     items: mystore[6]
        };

}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(IncomeProfile);
```

Console.log first print "undefined" then it print this:
[image]

Try add condition in render method `if (elems) { }` not helps

Comment: The error message means `elems` is not definied in the runtime. Hope this helps debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the following

```
var elems = this.props.items['course_list'];
 var copy = Object.assign({}, elems); 
 console.log(elems.course_list);
```